# Prestashop Change order status PS_OS_CANCELED to Decrease QTY instead to Increase

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I am using Prestashop 1.7.6.9 I need to set me PS_OS_CANCELED status to decrease product stock QTY.

I would be happy if anyone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override **changeIdOrderState** method
in */classes/order/OrderHistory.php*

Search for **PS_OS_CANCELED** there and you'll see where the quantity is getting increased.